# Point in a circle (geogebra question)

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry, quadrilateral

This is a screenshot of the ["Point on a circle"](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ytgtcpz9) lesson on GeoGebra:

[image]

I have to answer the lesson's first 3 question (shown below), and I could use some help. I tried for 3 days, and I don't seem to get it.

> 1. What do you notice? Any conjecture(s)? Proof(s)?
> 2. Can the diagonals of the four squares form a quadrilateral? If yes, does the order of the colored diagonals matter? Why or why not?
> 3. Under what circumstances can the diagonals of the four squares not form a quadrilateral?

- In the first question, I answered that I noticed that the ratio between the area of the circle and the area of the four squares is a constant $ \frac{\pi}{2}$. I'm still stuck in how to prove it, if anyone can give me a hint on how to start it will be great!
- In the second question: According to the third question, the answer is "yes, the diagonals can form a quadrilateral", but I don't see why. A quadrilateral has 4 edges, each two has a joint point, and here the only joint point is the joint point of all 4 squares, and it's impossible to make a quadrilateral? When i try, there is only 1 way for the diagonals to make a quadrilateral, and that is if the joint point of the 4 squares is in the middle of the circle and they are in the same size.
- And of course I cannot solve the third question because it is based on the second.

If your read it until here THANK YOU! I will be really thankful for who can help!

Comment: "Can the diagonals of the four squares form a quadrilateral?" according to the third question' the answer is yes, but I don't see why"  What if all four squares are equal?

Comment: "and here the only joint point is the joint point of all 4 squares" You can get the corner of the orange square to left of the corner of blue square.  ANd you can get the corner of the orange square to the right of the corner of the blue square.  Don't the corners have to pass each other at some point?

Comment: "there is only 1 way for the diagonals to make a quadrilateral, and that is if the joint point of the 4 squars is in the middle of the circle and they are in the same size"  Surely that is not impossible?

Comment: But I think that the second question about the diagonals is not if the 4 squares are equal, I think it's a special case if they are the same size because in the 3rd question they ask "Under what circumstances can the diagonals of the four squares *not* form a quadrilateral?
"

Comment: or maybe what they meant in the 3rd question is "Under what circumstances can the diagonals of the four squares form a quadrilateral? " without the not

Comment: Just answer what you *think* is correct.  If the only way they can form a quadrilateral is if the corners match up which only occurs if the point is in the center of the circle, then the answer to "under what circumstance con the diagonals of the four squares *not* form a quadrilateral" is "when the point is *not* in the center of the circle".... You seem to be having a hard time accepting that sometimes there is an integer bigger than $0$ and less than $2$.  There is.  It's called $1$.  It is a perfection acceptable answer.

Comment: The area of the inscribed square is $S=2r^2$ while the area of the circle is $C=\pi r^2$ so the ratio is $C/S=\pi/2$. Trivial. The sum of the squares area is constant and is equal to the area of the inscribed square. Not trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made all the correct observations already. You just seem to need some confirmation that your observations are indeed correct. So here are my answers to the questions:

1. From just the screenshot I would guess that the total area of the four squares is twice the radius squared. This is equivalent to your observation.
2. If the point is in the center of the circle, then all four squares are the same size, and they line up to form a larger square. The diagonals that then form a diamond (in fact a tilted square), which is a quadrilateral.
3. From the answer to the previous question, it is not hard to see that for the diagonals to form a quadrilateral, each pair of adjacent squares must line up. This happens for all four squares at once if and only if the point is at the center.

Of course you may want to go into more detail than I just did, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! This is a good start for me!